# Find an $\mathsf{L}^{p}$ space for financial markets with infinitely many risky assets

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, normed-spaces, finance

Given a sequence of random variables $\mathbf{x}=(X_{1},X_{2},\cdots
,X_{n},\cdots)$, with $X_{i}\in\mathsf{L}^{2}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathrm{P})$
for each $i$ such that $\left\Vert X_{i}\right\Vert =\operatorname{E}
(\left\vert X_{i}\right\vert ^{2})^{1/2}<+\infty$, $\sup(\left\Vert
X_{1}\right\Vert ,\left\Vert X_{2}\right\Vert ,\cdots,\left\Vert
X_{n}\right\Vert ,\cdots)<+\infty$, and $\inf(\left\Vert X_{1}\right\Vert
,\left\Vert X_{2}\right\Vert ,\cdots,\left\Vert X_{n}\right\Vert
,\cdots)=\sigma>0$.

Let $\mathbf{h}=(h_{1},h_{2},\cdots,h_{n},\cdots)\in
\ell^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real number, such that $h_{i}\in\mathbb{R}$
for each $i$, and $\left\Vert \mathbf{h}\right\Vert _{\infty}=\sup(\left\vert
h_{1}\right\vert ,\left\vert h_{2}\right\vert ,\cdots,\left\vert
h_{n}\right\vert ,\cdots)<+\infty$. Define $\mathbf{h}^{\prime}\mathbf{x}
=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}h_{i}X_{i}$ and
$$
\mathsf{S}=\left\{  \mathbf{h}^{\prime}\mathbf{x}:\mathbf{h}\in\ell^{\infty
},\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\operatorname{E}(\left\vert X_{i}\right\vert
)<+\infty\right\}
$$
Can I find some $p$ with $1<p<2$ such that $\mathsf{S}\subset\mathsf{L}^{p}
(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathrm{P})$. One may tighten or relax certain conditions
in the definition of $\mathsf{S}$.

Remark: In a financial market, $\mathbf{x}$ is the set of given risky assets
(infinitely many), and $\mathsf{S}$ is the payoff space of the market. Since
the market portfolio is $\mathbf{h}=\mathbf{1}=(1,1,1,\cdots)\in\ell^{\infty}
$, hence we require that the holdings $\mathbf{h}\in\ell^{\infty}$, and a
portfolio is an infinite linear combination.

- For the market portfolio, $Y=\mathbf{1}^{\prime}\mathbf{x}\notin\mathsf{L}
  ^{2}$: let $\operatorname{E}(X_{i}X_{j})=0$ for $i\neq j$, then
  $$
  \left\Vert Y\right\Vert ^2=\operatorname{E}\left(  \left\vert \sum_{i=1}
  ^{\infty}X_{i}\right\vert ^{2}\right)  =\sum_{i=1}^{\infty
  }\operatorname{E}\left(  \left\vert X_{i}\right\vert ^{2}\right)  
  \geq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sigma^2=+\infty
  $$
- For any portfolio $Y=\mathbf{h}^{\prime}\mathbf{x}\in\mathsf{S}$, there is
  $\operatorname{E}(\left\vert Y\right\vert )<+\infty$: by
  $$
  \left\vert Y\right\vert \leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\vert h_{i}X_{i}
  \right\vert \leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\vert h_{i}\right\vert \left\vert
  X_{i}\right\vert \leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\Vert \mathbf{h}\right\Vert
  _{\infty}\left\vert X_{i}\right\vert =\left\Vert \mathbf{h}\right\Vert
  _{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left\vert X_{i}\right\vert
  $$
  we have $\operatorname{E}(\left\vert Y\right\vert )\leq\left\Vert
  \mathbf{h}\right\Vert _{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\operatorname{E}(\left\vert
  X_{i}\right\vert )<+\infty$.

Comment: Do you have references that define portfolios as potentially infinite linear combinations of assets?

Comment: First, market portfolio is an infinite linear combination. Second, in APT (arbitrary pricing theory), portfolios are infinite linear combinations, e.g. [A General Approach to the Arbitrage Pricing Theory (APT)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1911083)